# Flexible Array Member to access union raw bytes

Tags: c, embedded, standards

On an embedded platform.

Assuming I'm receiving bytes from slave device through a serial line, where data are serialized and de-serialized correctly to ensure endianness and sizes of data is correct.

What I really want to achieve is to have the `struct test` with variable size to allow future expansion of the array member.

- Are there unexpected behavior on multi platform application?
- Are there parts of c standard that prohibit this kind of access?

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct test
{
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint32_t c[];
};

union test1
{
    struct test A;
    uint8_t B[256];
};

int main(void)
{
    union test1 test2;

    for (uint32_t i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        test2.B[i] = i;
    }

    for (size_t i=0; i<(sizeof(test2.B)/sizeof(uint32_t))-2; i++)
        printf("Test: 0x%08X\n", test2.A.c[i]);
}
```

Comment: I assume that the slave will send variable-sized data? And that the protocol can not be changed? Also, the size of `B` in the union should probably be `sizeof(struct test) + 256`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the protocol sopports different types of slave devices, for different master application. Master can enable or disable resources of slave device. So based on configurations and types of slave can some messages can have different sizes. It is a moltipoint handshake protocol, so different slaves on the same "net".

Comment: As for the validity of what you're doing, The C11 specification (in §6.5.2.3 footnote 95) says that type punning using unions is allowed, but might be a [trap representation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-ctypes3/#N100A5).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude about the size, my struct is a lot more complex than the posted one. I have header and multiple payload. the `uint8_t B[256];` is the raw bytes access to messages.

Comment: So no more than 256 bytes will be sent? Then your example is flawed as it will go out of bounds of the flexible array. :) By the way, you *do* "pack" your structures, so you don't have alignment/padding issues?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oopps. I edited. I avoid to pack(1) struct to avoid unaligned access. I'm taking care of the padding filling the buffer into the right place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to consider:

- Alignment. You cannot portably assume that a struct or union will not have padding bytes. In theory, some systems with obscure alignment requirements in relation to the size of int, may result in padding bytes inside the struct.

  Since that scenario is mostly theoretical, you can ensure that it won't happen by adding

  ```
  _Static_assert(sizeof(struct test) == sizeof(int)+sizeof(int),
             "Padding detected!");
  ```
- Endianess, as noted in the question, is a real concern, which has to be handled somewhere.
- Signed `int` probably doesn't make any sense in a union, or anywhere else in an embedded system for that matter. These could cause havoc in many ways, though not in any of the code posted. They should be replaced with types of deterministic size and signedness from stdint.h.
- Type punning. The type punning is fine although implementation-defined. I don't see why your code would ever cause problems on a regular two's complement system. But you could probably, in theory, get portability issues with wildly exotic systems that don't use two's complement, but implement padding bits, trap bits etc. I wouldn't be overly concerned about portability to such barely existing systems.
- C standards. You obviously won't be able to port flexible array member code to C90 systems. It might compile there but invoke undefined behavior. Also, some retarded branch of the standard committee made `stdint.h` optional in C11. I wouldn't be concerned about that though.

Overall I would say the code is fine and portable to all useful systems, as long as you handle endianess somewhere and get rid of the `int`.

Comment: yes, stdint is mandatory, I wrote a bad sample code ;). So you are telling that I can found systems where `offsetof` does not return the correct displacement of a struct member?

Comment: @LPs You probably won't find any, although the C standard does not forbid obscure, mostly fictional systems (like a system with 5 byte alignment). There might exist some very exotic DSPs and such, but anyone trying to write portable C code with them in mind is likely wasting the time (and DSP code is, afaik, still mostly written in assembler anyway).

Answer (score 2):

In C89 and the original publication of C99, writing to one member of a `union` and reading from another has implementation-defined behavior.  In TC1 to C99, it was changed to *unspecified* behavior.  Either way, the practical implications are the same: you *can* write to one member of a union and read back from another without worrying about demons flying out of your nose; the standard doesn't tell you what *value* you will get, but with knowledge of the implementation it should be predictable.

Having said that, you are very likely to run into problems with padding in `struct test`, endianness inconsistencies, and so on.  Some of these problems can be mitigated by using `stdint.h` fixed-width types instead of `int`, and using unsigned types to the maximum extent possible.  I would also strongly recommend you write an explicit conversion function from whatever definite endianness your external protocol is in, e.g.

```
static int32_t
be32_to_cpu(const unsigned char *p)
{
    uint32_t x = 0;
    x |= ((uint32_t)p[0]) << 24;
    x |= ((uint32_t)p[1]) << 16;
    x |= ((uint32_t)p[2]) <<  8;
    x |= ((uint32_t)p[3]) <<  0;
    return (int32_t)x;
}
```

and manually copy from an `unsigned char` buffer with manually computed offsets, e.g.

```
struct test
{
    int32_t a;
    int32_t b;
    int32_t c[62];
}

void convert_block(struct test *restrict out,
                   const unsigned char *restrict buf)
{
    out->a = be32_to_cpu(&buf[0]);
    out->b = be32_to_cpu(&buf[4]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 62; i++)
        out->c[i] = be32_to_cpu(&buf[4 * (i+2)]);
}
```

Modern compilers will recognize the idiom in `be32_to_cpu` and generate optimal code.  For little-endian, just reverse the sequence of shifts.  Note that you must assemble the value in an unsigned variable and convert to signed afterward, because shifting into the sign bit has undefined behavior.

If your wire protocol sends packets of variable size, then presumably there is a size field, and you will need to use that both to know when to stop reading, and how big to make the buffer:

```
struct test
{
    uint32_t size;
    int32_t b;
    int32_t c[]; /* SIZE/4 - 2 values */
};

struct test *
read_block(int fd)
{
    char b1[4];
    if (read(fd, b1, 4) < 4) abort();
    uint32_t size = be32u_to_cpu(b1);

    char b2[size - 4];
    if (read(fd, b2, size - 4) < size - 4) abort();

    struct test *out = malloc(size);
    out->size = size;
    out->b = be32s_to_cpu(&b2[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size/4 - 2; i++)
        out->c[i] = be32s_to_cpu(&b2[(i+1)*4]);

    return out;
}
```

Proper handling of errors and short reads left as an exercise.

Comment: Ok. I did the serialization and de-serialization of the data as you shown. I also take care of offset of each member before to fill the "raw bytes array" to match the struct. What I want to achieve is to have the struct test with variable size to allow future expansion of the array member.

Comment: No... this is not correct. I just went through this debate with some C guru here on SO and the conclusion was that C has always allowed type punning through unions - it is merely implementation-defined behavior. C90 6.3.2.3 `"With one exception, if a member of a union object is accessed after a value has been stored in a different member of the object, the behavior is implementation-defined (41)."` The note 41 explicitly mentions type punning.

Comment: Thanks for your edit with example, but as I wrote, I'm talking, mainly, about embedded device: `malloc` is evil ;) The protocol will be also a pre-compiled lib to be used on various project, so static allocation will be implemented.

Comment: @Lundin I would want to close-read C90 again myself before I actually *believed* that, but as I am not in the mood to do that today, I will take your word for it and change "undefined" to "implementation-defined".

Comment: @LPs Flexible array members are really only designed for use with `malloc`.  If you can't use `malloc`, use a fixed-size input buffer which is as big as it will ever need to be, and define structures of concrete size corresponding to each packet layout (for any variable-length fields, you also use arrays that are as big as they will ever need to be).

Comment: @zwol Its just that text + the foot note, pretty clearly written. Easy to mix up this with C++ though, where type punning has always been UB as far as I know.